# Visible layout after a list scroll

Tags: android

I need help figuring out the type of view  for my app.

We have new design here, but I stuck and do not know what kind of view.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JQUc.png)

The view will visible after the list stop scrolling.
Please give me name of view in this case, thank a lot!

Comment: There isn't a View which has the same functionality and ready to be used. You need to create it yourself. It really depends on your parent layout and the scroll behaviour. You can use `CoordinatorLayout` and create a custom scroll behaviour which fits your need.

Comment: you can use Floating action bar or create a custom layout of your own as per your needs.

Comment: take parent layout as relative layout and inside that layout make your custom view and give alighParentBottom="true" and give marginBottom="20dp" its done